# populate List with SolidColorBrush brushes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to populate a List with all of the predefined SolidColorBrushes available in WP7.1 but I am having trouble doing this via code. I have accomplished this manually with a short list of test colors, which works ok, but there are over a hundred different predefined colors and I know there must be a correct method, although I am unsure of how to accomplish this. What I have so far is as follows

MainPage.xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>
            <!--<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="ColorList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="88" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >-->
            <toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="ColorList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="ColorList_Tap">
                <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,12,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Brush}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,10,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>


            </toolkit:MultiselectList>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    List<ColorItem> solidColorBrushList;

    public ColorListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        solidColorBrushList = new List<ColorItem>()
        {
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,27,161,226)), Name = "blue" },     
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,160,80,0)), Name = "brown" },      
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 51,153,51)), Name = "green" },    
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,162,193,57)), Name = "lime" },    
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,216,0,115)), Name = "magenta" },  
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,240,150,9)), Name = "mango" },    
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,230,113,184)), Name = "pink" },   
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,162,0,255)), Name = "purple" },   
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,229,20,0)), Name = "red" },       
            new ColorItem { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,171,169)), Name = "teal" }
        };

        this.ColorList.ItemsSource = solidColorBrushList;

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ColorListPage_Loaded);
    }

    void ColorListPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //show checkboxes when page is loaded
        this.ColorList.IsSelectionEnabled = true;
    }
}

public class ColorItem
{
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the proper method to call all brushes and their respective names to populate the multiselectlist? 
Also as a side note, for some reason my multiselect list cuts off the text when displayed in the page, is there a way to stretch the list to the width of the screen so the rectangle and text may both be displayed without being cut off?

Comment: thanks for the tip! I did have another question regarding @Chris 's solution about accessing all the predefined colors, instead of only about 10 which are populating the multiselectlist. Any idea of how to get the entire list as shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use reflection to pull out all the `Color` entries in `Colors` and build brushes out of those.

You'll have to forgive me, I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment so I'm whipping this off in notepad with API off the top of my head.

```
List<ColorItem> solidColorBrushList = new List<ColorItem>();

PropertyInfo[] colorProperties = typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
foreach (PropertyInfo colorProperty in colorProperties)
{
    //could probably omit this check; I think all static properties of Colors are of type Color
    if (colorProperty.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
    {
        Color color = (Color)colorProperty.GetValue(null, null);
        string colorName = colorPropertyName;
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);

        ColorItem item = new ColorItem() { Brush = brush, Name = colorName };
        solidColorBrushList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

So yeah, I might have gotten a function parameter wrong or maybe you need to tweak the `BindingFlags`, but that should give you a good starting point.  When I get the time tomorrow (and access to Visual Studio) I'll double-check and fix it if necessary.

EDIT: Just figured I'd paste the class we have at work that copied over the full .NET 4.0 listing of colors to our own internal `Color` struct in case you hadn't gotten around to it.  Maybe it'll save you time:

```
public static class Colors
{
    private static readonly Color m_Transparent = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_AliceBlue = Color.FromRgb(240, 248, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_AntiqueWhite = Color.FromRgb(250, 235, 215);
    private static readonly Color m_Aqua = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_Aquamarine = Color.FromRgb(127, 255, 212);
    private static readonly Color m_Azure = Color.FromRgb(240, 255, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_Beige = Color.FromRgb(245, 245, 220);
    private static readonly Color m_Bisque = Color.FromRgb(255, 228, 196);
    private static readonly Color m_Black = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_BlanchedAlmond = Color.FromRgb(255, 235, 205);
    private static readonly Color m_Blue = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_BlueViolet = Color.FromRgb(138, 43, 226);
    private static readonly Color m_Brown = Color.FromRgb(165, 42, 42);
    private static readonly Color m_BurlyWood = Color.FromRgb(222, 184, 135);
    private static readonly Color m_CadetBlue = Color.FromRgb(95, 158, 160);
    private static readonly Color m_Chartreuse = Color.FromRgb(127, 255, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_Chocolate = Color.FromRgb(210, 105, 30);
    private static readonly Color m_Coral = Color.FromRgb(255, 127, 80);
    private static readonly Color m_CornflowerBlue = Color.FromRgb(100, 149, 237);
    private static readonly Color m_Cornsilk = Color.FromRgb(255, 248, 220);
    private static readonly Color m_Crimson = Color.FromRgb(220, 20, 60);
    private static readonly Color m_Cyan = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkBlue = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 139);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkCyan = Color.FromRgb(0, 139, 139);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkGoldenrod = Color.FromRgb(184, 134, 11);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkGray = Color.FromRgb(169, 169, 169);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 100, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkKhaki = Color.FromRgb(189, 183, 107);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkMagenta = Color.FromRgb(139, 0, 139);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkOliveGreen = Color.FromRgb(85, 107, 47);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkOrange = Color.FromRgb(255, 140, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkOrchid = Color.FromRgb(153, 50, 204);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkRed = Color.FromRgb(139, 0, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkSalmon = Color.FromRgb(233, 150, 122);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkSeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(143, 188, 139);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkSlateBlue = Color.FromRgb(72, 61, 139);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkSlateGray = Color.FromRgb(47, 79, 79);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkTurquoise = Color.FromRgb(0, 206, 209);
    private static readonly Color m_DarkViolet = Color.FromRgb(148, 0, 211);
    private static readonly Color m_DeepPink = Color.FromRgb(255, 20, 147);
    private static readonly Color m_DeepSkyBlue = Color.FromRgb(0, 191, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_DimGray = Color.FromRgb(105, 105, 105);
    private static readonly Color m_DodgerBlue = Color.FromRgb(30, 144, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_Firebrick = Color.FromRgb(178, 34, 34);
    private static readonly Color m_FloralWhite = Color.FromRgb(255, 250, 240);
    private static readonly Color m_ForestGreen = Color.FromRgb(34, 139, 34);
    private static readonly Color m_Fuchsia = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_Gainsboro = Color.FromRgb(220, 220, 220);
    private static readonly Color m_GhostWhite = Color.FromRgb(248, 248, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_Gold = Color.FromRgb(255, 215, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_Goldenrod = Color.FromRgb(218, 165, 32);
    private static readonly Color m_Gray = Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 128);
    private static readonly Color m_Green = Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_GreenYellow = Color.FromRgb(173, 255, 47);
    private static readonly Color m_Honeydew = Color.FromRgb(240, 255, 240);
    private static readonly Color m_HotPink = Color.FromRgb(255, 105, 180);
    private static readonly Color m_IndianRed = Color.FromRgb(205, 92, 92);
    private static readonly Color m_Indigo = Color.FromRgb(75, 0, 130);
    private static readonly Color m_Ivory = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 240);
    private static readonly Color m_Khaki = Color.FromRgb(240, 230, 140);
    private static readonly Color m_Lavender = Color.FromRgb(230, 230, 250);
    private static readonly Color m_LavenderBlush = Color.FromRgb(255, 240, 245);
    private static readonly Color m_LawnGreen = Color.FromRgb(124, 252, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_LemonChiffon = Color.FromRgb(255, 250, 205);
    private static readonly Color m_LightBlue = Color.FromRgb(173, 216, 230);
    private static readonly Color m_LightCoral = Color.FromRgb(240, 128, 128);
    private static readonly Color m_LightCyan = Color.FromRgb(224, 255, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_LightGoldenrodYellow = Color.FromRgb(250, 250, 210);
    private static readonly Color m_LightGreen = Color.FromRgb(144, 238, 144);
    private static readonly Color m_LightGray = Color.FromRgb(211, 211, 211);
    private static readonly Color m_LightPink = Color.FromRgb(255, 182, 193);
    private static readonly Color m_LightSalmon = Color.FromRgb(255, 160, 122);
    private static readonly Color m_LightSeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(32, 178, 170);
    private static readonly Color m_LightSkyBlue = Color.FromRgb(135, 206, 250);
    private static readonly Color m_LightSlateGray = Color.FromRgb(119, 136, 153);
    private static readonly Color m_LightSteelBlue = Color.FromRgb(176, 196, 222);
    private static readonly Color m_LightYellow = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 224);
    private static readonly Color m_Lime = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_LimeGreen = Color.FromRgb(50, 205, 50);
    private static readonly Color m_Linen = Color.FromRgb(250, 240, 230);
    private static readonly Color m_Magenta = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_Maroon = Color.FromRgb(128, 0, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumAquamarine = Color.FromRgb(102, 205, 170);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumBlue = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 205);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumOrchid = Color.FromRgb(186, 85, 211);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumPurple = Color.FromRgb(147, 112, 219);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumSeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(60, 179, 113);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumSlateBlue = Color.FromRgb(123, 104, 238);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumSpringGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 250, 154);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumTurquoise = Color.FromRgb(72, 209, 204);
    private static readonly Color m_MediumVioletRed = Color.FromRgb(199, 21, 133);
    private static readonly Color m_MidnightBlue = Color.FromRgb(25, 25, 112);
    private static readonly Color m_MintCream = Color.FromRgb(245, 255, 250);
    private static readonly Color m_MistyRose = Color.FromRgb(255, 228, 225);
    private static readonly Color m_Moccasin = Color.FromRgb(255, 228, 181);
    private static readonly Color m_NavajoWhite = Color.FromRgb(255, 222, 173);
    private static readonly Color m_Navy = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 128);
    private static readonly Color m_OldLace = Color.FromRgb(253, 245, 230);
    private static readonly Color m_Olive = Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_OliveDrab = Color.FromRgb(107, 142, 35);
    private static readonly Color m_Orange = Color.FromRgb(255, 165, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_OrangeRed = Color.FromRgb(255, 69, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_Orchid = Color.FromRgb(218, 112, 214);
    private static readonly Color m_PaleGoldenrod = Color.FromRgb(238, 232, 170);
    private static readonly Color m_PaleGreen = Color.FromRgb(152, 251, 152);
    private static readonly Color m_PaleTurquoise = Color.FromRgb(175, 238, 238);
    private static readonly Color m_PaleVioletRed = Color.FromRgb(219, 112, 147);
    private static readonly Color m_PapayaWhip = Color.FromRgb(255, 239, 213);
    private static readonly Color m_PeachPuff = Color.FromRgb(255, 218, 185);
    private static readonly Color m_Peru = Color.FromRgb(205, 133, 63);
    private static readonly Color m_Pink = Color.FromRgb(255, 192, 203);
    private static readonly Color m_Plum = Color.FromRgb(221, 160, 221);
    private static readonly Color m_PowderBlue = Color.FromRgb(176, 224, 230);
    private static readonly Color m_Purple = Color.FromRgb(128, 0, 128);
    private static readonly Color m_Red = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_RosyBrown = Color.FromRgb(188, 143, 143);
    private static readonly Color m_RoyalBlue = Color.FromRgb(65, 105, 225);
    private static readonly Color m_SaddleBrown = Color.FromRgb(139, 69, 19);
    private static readonly Color m_Salmon = Color.FromRgb(250, 128, 114);
    private static readonly Color m_SandyBrown = Color.FromRgb(244, 164, 96);
    private static readonly Color m_SeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(46, 139, 87);
    private static readonly Color m_SeaShell = Color.FromRgb(255, 245, 238);
    private static readonly Color m_Sienna = Color.FromRgb(160, 82, 45);
    private static readonly Color m_Silver = Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192);
    private static readonly Color m_SkyBlue = Color.FromRgb(135, 206, 235);
    private static readonly Color m_SlateBlue = Color.FromRgb(106, 90, 205);
    private static readonly Color m_SlateGray = Color.FromRgb(112, 128, 144);
    private static readonly Color m_Snow = Color.FromRgb(255, 250, 250);
    private static readonly Color m_SpringGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 127);
    private static readonly Color m_SteelBlue = Color.FromRgb(70, 130, 180);
    private static readonly Color m_Tan = Color.FromRgb(210, 180, 140);
    private static readonly Color m_Teal = Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 128);
    private static readonly Color m_Thistle = Color.FromRgb(216, 191, 216);
    private static readonly Color m_Tomato = Color.FromRgb(255, 99, 71);
    private static readonly Color m_Turquoise = Color.FromRgb(64, 224, 208);
    private static readonly Color m_Violet = Color.FromRgb(238, 130, 238);
    private static readonly Color m_Wheat = Color.FromRgb(245, 222, 179);
    private static readonly Color m_White = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
    private static readonly Color m_WhiteSmoke = Color.FromRgb(245, 245, 245);
    private static readonly Color m_Yellow = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0);
    private static readonly Color m_YellowGreen = Color.FromRgb(154, 205, 50);

    public static Color Transparent { get { return m_Transparent; } }

    public static Color AliceBlue { get { return m_AliceBlue; } }

    public static Color AntiqueWhite { get { return m_AntiqueWhite; } }

    public static Color Aqua { get { return m_Aqua; } }

    public static Color Aquamarine { get { return m_Aquamarine; } }

    public static Color Azure { get { return m_Azure; } }

    public static Color Beige { get { return m_Beige; } }

    public static Color Bisque { get { return m_Bisque; } }

    public static Color Black { get { return m_Black; } }

    public static Color BlanchedAlmond { get { return m_BlanchedAlmond; } }

    public static Color Blue { get { return m_Blue; } }

    public static Color BlueViolet { get { return m_BlueViolet; } }

    public static Color Brown { get { return m_Brown; } }

    public static Color BurlyWood { get { return m_BurlyWood; } }

    public static Color CadetBlue { get { return m_CadetBlue; } }

    public static Color Chartreuse { get { return m_Chartreuse; } }

    public static Color Chocolate { get { return m_Chocolate; } }

    public static Color Coral { get { return m_Coral; } }

    public static Color CornflowerBlue { get { return m_CornflowerBlue; } }

    public static Color Cornsilk { get { return m_Cornsilk; } }

    public static Color Crimson { get { return m_Crimson; } }

    public static Color Cyan { get { return m_Cyan; } }

    public static Color DarkBlue { get { return m_DarkBlue; } }

    public static Color DarkCyan { get { return m_DarkCyan; } }

    public static Color DarkGoldenrod { get { return m_DarkGoldenrod; } }

    public static Color DarkGray { get { return m_DarkGray; } }

    public static Color DarkGreen { get { return m_DarkGreen; } }

    public static Color DarkKhaki { get { return m_DarkKhaki; } }

    public static Color DarkMagenta { get { return m_DarkMagenta; } }

    public static Color DarkOliveGreen { get { return m_DarkOliveGreen; } }

    public static Color DarkOrange { get { return m_DarkOrange; } }

    public static Color DarkOrchid { get { return m_DarkOrchid; } }

    public static Color DarkRed { get { return m_DarkRed; } }

    public static Color DarkSalmon { get { return m_DarkSalmon; } }

    public static Color DarkSeaGreen { get { return m_DarkSeaGreen; } }

    public static Color DarkSlateBlue { get { return m_DarkSlateBlue; } }

    public static Color DarkSlateGray { get { return m_DarkSlateGray; } }

    public static Color DarkTurquoise { get { return m_DarkTurquoise; } }

    public static Color DarkViolet { get { return m_DarkViolet; } }

    public static Color DeepPink { get { return m_DeepPink; } }

    public static Color DeepSkyBlue { get { return m_DeepSkyBlue; } }

    public static Color DimGray { get { return m_DimGray; } }

    public static Color DodgerBlue { get { return m_DodgerBlue; } }

    public static Color Firebrick { get { return m_Firebrick; } }

    public static Color FloralWhite { get { return m_FloralWhite; } }

    public static Color ForestGreen { get { return m_ForestGreen; } }

    public static Color Fuchsia { get { return m_Fuchsia; } }

    public static Color Gainsboro { get { return m_Gainsboro; } }

    public static Color GhostWhite { get { return m_GhostWhite; } }

    public static Color Gold { get { return m_Gold; } }

    public static Color Goldenrod { get { return m_Goldenrod; } }

    public static Color Gray { get { return m_Gray; } }

    public static Color Green { get { return m_Green; } }

    public static Color GreenYellow { get { return m_GreenYellow; } }

    public static Color Honeydew { get { return m_Honeydew; } }

    public static Color HotPink { get { return m_HotPink; } }

    public static Color IndianRed { get { return m_IndianRed; } }

    public static Color Indigo { get { return m_Indigo; } }

    public static Color Ivory { get { return m_Ivory; } }

    public static Color Khaki { get { return m_Khaki; } }

    public static Color Lavender { get { return m_Lavender; } }

    public static Color LavenderBlush { get { return m_LavenderBlush; } }

    public static Color LawnGreen { get { return m_LawnGreen; } }

    public static Color LemonChiffon { get { return m_LemonChiffon; } }

    public static Color LightBlue { get { return m_LightBlue; } }

    public static Color LightCoral { get { return m_LightCoral; } }

    public static Color LightCyan { get { return m_LightCyan; } }

    public static Color LightGoldenrodYellow { get { return m_LightGoldenrodYellow; } }

    public static Color LightGreen { get { return m_LightGreen; } }

    public static Color LightGray { get { return m_LightGray; } }

    public static Color LightPink { get { return m_LightPink; } }

    public static Color LightSalmon { get { return m_LightSalmon; } }

    public static Color LightSeaGreen { get { return m_LightSeaGreen; } }

    public static Color LightSkyBlue { get { return m_LightSkyBlue; } }

    public static Color LightSlateGray { get { return m_LightSlateGray; } }

    public static Color LightSteelBlue { get { return m_LightSteelBlue; } }

    public static Color LightYellow { get { return m_LightYellow; } }

    public static Color Lime { get { return m_Lime; } }

    public static Color LimeGreen { get { return m_LimeGreen; } }

    public static Color Linen { get { return m_Linen; } }

    public static Color Magenta { get { return m_Magenta; } }

    public static Color Maroon { get { return m_Maroon; } }

    public static Color MediumAquamarine { get { return m_MediumAquamarine; } }

    public static Color MediumBlue { get { return m_MediumBlue; } }

    public static Color MediumOrchid { get { return m_MediumOrchid; } }

    public static Color MediumPurple { get { return m_MediumPurple; } }

    public static Color MediumSeaGreen { get { return m_MediumSeaGreen; } }

    public static Color MediumSlateBlue { get { return m_MediumSlateBlue; } }

    public static Color MediumSpringGreen { get { return m_MediumSpringGreen; } }

    public static Color MediumTurquoise { get { return m_MediumTurquoise; } }

    public static Color MediumVioletRed { get { return m_MediumVioletRed; } }

    public static Color MidnightBlue { get { return m_MidnightBlue; } }

    public static Color MintCream { get { return m_MintCream; } }

    public static Color MistyRose { get { return m_MistyRose; } }

    public static Color Moccasin { get { return m_Moccasin; } }

    public static Color NavajoWhite { get { return m_NavajoWhite; } }

    public static Color Navy { get { return m_Navy; } }

    public static Color OldLace { get { return m_OldLace; } }

    public static Color Olive { get { return m_Olive; } }

    public static Color OliveDrab { get { return m_OliveDrab; } }

    public static Color Orange { get { return m_Orange; } }

    public static Color OrangeRed { get { return m_OrangeRed; } }

    public static Color Orchid { get { return m_Orchid; } }

    public static Color PaleGoldenrod { get { return m_PaleGoldenrod; } }

    public static Color PaleGreen { get { return m_PaleGreen; } }

    public static Color PaleTurquoise { get { return m_PaleTurquoise; } }

    public static Color PaleVioletRed { get { return m_PaleVioletRed; } }

    public static Color PapayaWhip { get { return m_PapayaWhip; } }

    public static Color PeachPuff { get { return m_PeachPuff; } }

    public static Color Peru { get { return m_Peru; } }

    public static Color Pink { get { return m_Pink; } }

    public static Color Plum { get { return m_Plum; } }

    public static Color PowderBlue { get { return m_PowderBlue; } }

    public static Color Purple { get { return m_Purple; } }

    public static Color Red { get { return m_Red; } }

    public static Color RosyBrown { get { return m_RosyBrown; } }

    public static Color RoyalBlue { get { return m_RoyalBlue; } }

    public static Color SaddleBrown { get { return m_SaddleBrown; } }

    public static Color Salmon { get { return m_Salmon; } }

    public static Color SandyBrown { get { return m_SandyBrown; } }

    public static Color SeaGreen { get { return m_SeaGreen; } }

    public static Color SeaShell { get { return m_SeaShell; } }

    public static Color Sienna { get { return m_Sienna; } }

    public static Color Silver { get { return m_Silver; } }

    public static Color SkyBlue { get { return m_SkyBlue; } }

    public static Color SlateBlue { get { return m_SlateBlue; } }

    public static Color SlateGray { get { return m_SlateGray; } }

    public static Color Snow { get { return m_Snow; } }

    public static Color SpringGreen { get { return m_SpringGreen; } }

    public static Color SteelBlue { get { return m_SteelBlue; } }

    public static Color Tan { get { return m_Tan; } }

    public static Color Teal { get { return m_Teal; } }

    public static Color Thistle { get { return m_Thistle; } }

    public static Color Tomato { get { return m_Tomato; } }

    public static Color Turquoise { get { return m_Turquoise; } }

    public static Color Violet { get { return m_Violet; } }

    public static Color Wheat { get { return m_Wheat; } }

    public static Color White { get { return m_White; } }

    public static Color WhiteSmoke { get { return m_WhiteSmoke; } }

    public static Color Yellow { get { return m_Yellow; } }

    public static Color YellowGreen { get { return m_YellowGreen; } }
}
```

Comment: your solution worked, although only about 10 predefined colors were populated. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx there are over a hundred predefined color options, which I can see when attempting to fill the rectangle manually from xaml. How do I access all of these colors?

Comment: Ahh, this is because it's for Silverlight (Windows phone), right?  Silverlight's System.Windows.Media.Colors class only has about a dozen colours (don't ask me why) whereas the full .NET 4.0 has a bajillion.  See the Silverlight version of the page you linked: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors%28VS.95%29.aspx  So how can you get around this? Maybe just what you did redefining each one. :-/  Might just have to bite the bullet.

Comment: It seems that the full .Net 4.0 uses the PresentationCore.dll whereas the wp7 silverlight uses the System.Windows.dll, would it be possible to reference PresentationCore.dll in a wp7 project (System.Windows.dll is referenced by default)?

Comment: The DLLs aren't compatible, sorry.  I think the best bet might just be to bite the bullet and create your own static class with readonly colours that you want to include.

Comment: Something I do in situations like this is use LINQPad (although VS will do just as well) to print out code for me.  Reference the WPF PresentationCore and run this code, and then loop through and output the 'new ColorItem(...Color.FromArgb(..., ..., ...' line, replacing the FromArgb arguments with your color codes.

Comment: @Matthew I posted the class we made at work that copies the full .NET 4.0 colors over in case you hadn't done that yet; maybe it'll save you some time.

Comment: Thanks @Chris unfortunately I had to go ahead and hard code it already.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is about the same as Chris's, but I thought it would be worth posting as I got mine down to one statement (and it seems a pity to just delete it):

```
var colors = typeof(Colors)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name,
                  p => new SolidColorBrush((Color)p.GetValue(null, null))
                 );
```

Edit: Including Chris's suggestion:

```
var colors = typeof(Colors)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(p => new ColorItem()
                 {
                     Name = p.Name,
                     Brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)p.GetValue(null, null))
                 }
           ).ToList();
```

Comment: One of these days I gotta really dive head-first into Linq. +1

Comment: Cheers :)  It's definitely worth it.  I find myself getting frustrated when I can't use them now.

Comment: Could you use something like `.Select(p => new ColorItem() { Name = p.Name, Brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)p.GetValue(null, null))})` instead of `ToDictionary` to get to his data type?

Comment: Sure, that's a good way to do it.  One thing to look out for though is to add a ToList(), ToArray(), etc call at the end of any statements like this, otherwise the .Select(...) will be reevaluated every time you use the collection.  This can be slow and cause some unexpected side-effects if you expect an object from the list to still be in the list later.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mr Penguin's answer, this lists the ColorCode as a string value which can be converted (`ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(..)`) just as the color name itself. Here is a Linqpad output:

```
typeof(Colors)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)p.GetValue(null, null)),
    })
    .Select(p => new { p.Name, ColorCode = p.Brush.ToString(), p.Brush})
.Dump();
```

[image]