# Creating .NET equivalent Colors static class in Mono Android (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, .net, mono, xamarin.android

A lot of Canvas methods in the Android API require a Paint object to be defined in order to define a color. The method for doing this is,

```
Paint myPaintObject = new Paint();
myPaintObject.Color = Color.Red;
canvas.DrawRect(..., myPaintObject);
```

it would be better if it looked like this,

```
canvas.DrawRect(..., Colors.Red);
```

A solution class might look like this...

```
public static class Colors
{
    public static Paint Red { get { return GetColors(Color.Red); } }
    public static Paint Black { get { return GetColors(Color.Black); } }

    private static Paint GetColors(Color color)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint ();
        paint.Color = color;
        return paint;
    }
}
```

but it would suck to have to create getters for every color available. Any ideas for making this easier?

edit: LINQ is a pretty good solution for this. Per @ChrisSinclair's comment regarding [populate List with SolidColorBrush brushes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924252/populate-list-with-solidcolorbrush-brushes)

```
this.Colors = typeof(Color)
    .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | 
                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, 
                      p => new Paint() 
                      { Color = ((Color)p.GetValue(null, null)) });
```

When called, looks like,

```
canvas.DrawRect(..., Colors["Red"]);
```

Comment: you might also want to cache those on first use..

Comment: @MikyDinescu: AKA, memory leak

Comment: @SLaks I was wondering if that would be an issue

Comment: You could write a quick LINQPad script to [iterate all the existing predefined colors and create the class for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924252/populate-list-with-solidcolorbrush-brushes) (complete with lazy properties or `readonly` fields or whatever underlying design you wish)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Not bad, I'll add the code as an edit. There are caveats that still need to be looked into I think.

Comment: @ferr: I didn't mean to use reflection at _runtime_, but rather use it to help create a compile-time equivalent list of `Paints` or `Colors` to use, kind of like `Paints.Red` as you have but saving you the aggravation of manually writing the many many dozens of predefined colours. I think it would be unnecessary (even dangerous) to lookup the colours by string name; ripe for typos or for colours which don't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that you'd have to know the color name in order to fetch it, an obvious disadvantage as well. I'll see about using it to create something compile-time specific..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just recommend an extension method to convert from `Color` to `Paint`:

```
 public static Paint AsPaint(this Color color)
 {
    Paint paint = new Paint ();
    paint.Color = color;
    return paint;          
 }
```

This would allow you to write, for any color:

```
canvas.DrawRect(..., Color.Red.AsPaint());
```

One advantage here is that you're not hiding the fact that you're creating a `Paint` instance each time.  Using `Colors.Red` suggests that you're creating a `Color`, not a `Paint`, and masks that it's being constructed with each call.

Otherwise, if you wish to make a `Colors` class with each property, you'll need a property per `Color` you with to support.  This could be done by scripting the creation of the source file, but there is no direct way to create all of these "colors" without writing a property per color.

Comment: I like it, not perfect but better than the approach I was ending up on!