# how can I change the color of my text while I type in the text box by using the colors in combo box?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, textbox

I created a Combo Box which includes all colors in Colors class. I'd like to change TextBox's foreground color by selecting the color from ComboBox. How can I do that?

And can you also explain the logic in {Binding Name}, I did not understand why I used Name keyword but it worked.

```
<StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="CBox" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" FontSize="20"/>
                     
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox x:Name="tBox"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CBox.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();       
}
```

---

I tried this approach and it gave error

```
tBox.Foreground = (Colors)CBox.SelectedItem;
```

---

Edit : The main problem was binding TextBox.
I simply fixed problem by changing TextBox code to this :

```
<TextBox Foreground="{Binding ElementName=CBox, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
```

but Clemens' approach is better so I proceed to use it.

Comment: `TextBox`'s `Foreground` property is of type `Brush` as you can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground - but you are trying to set an instance of type `Colors` - so I would recommend looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924252/populate-list-with-solidcolorbrush-brushes

Comment: or use `tBox.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Colors)CBox.SelectedItem);` | as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727491/programmatically-set-textblock-foreground-color

Comment: There should be `(Color)CBox.SelectedItem`, not Colors. And it would of course only work if you assign a collection of Color instances to the ItemsSource property, not a collection of PropertyInfo.

Comment: @Clemens - didn't even notice the `GetProperties()` well that atleast explains why `{Binding Name}` works, couldn't figure out why OP used `Name` (OP themself don't really know why) but I didn't give it much thought - `Name` is working because `PropertyInfo` has a property `Name` - as you can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-6.0#properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to assign a collection of anonymous objects with a `Name` and a `Brush` property to the ItemsSource of the ComboBox. The code below uses all the public static `Brush` properties of the `Brushes` class, instead of the `Color` properties of the `Colors` class.

The expression below first gets all public static properties of the [`System.Windows.Media.Brushes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) class, similar to what you already did for the `Colors` class. Then it maps this collection of `PropertyInfo` objects to a collection of instances of an anonymous class with a `Name` and a `Brush` property, by means of the [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) method. The Brush is created by calling the [`GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0) method of each PropertyInfo.

```
CBox.ItemsSource = typeof(Brushes)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(p => new { Name = p.Name, Brush = p.GetValue(null) });
```

Then bind this data like shown below. The `Foreground` property of the TextBox is bound to the `Brush` property of the selected item, i.e. the selected instance of the anonymous class.

```
<ComboBox Name="CBox" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Brush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

<TextBox Foreground="{Binding SelectedItem.Brush, ElementName=CBox}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand what happened I just started working with WPF this week. Can You explain what you did with CBox.ItemSource, and TextBox binding.

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks, after searching System.Linq and Select method I understood your code. I got one last question. Why did we  use null with GetValue method? GetValue(null)?

Comment: Because the properties are static. There is no class instance of which you would get the property value.